How do I manually specify a chain spec with zombienet?
I would like to specify a chain spec for zombienet manually. How do I do that?

[relaychain]
chain = "paseo-local"
chain_spec_path = "./my-chain-spec.json"


[[relaychain.nodes]]
name = "alice"
validator = true

[[relaychain.nodes]]
name = "bob"
validator = true

You can use relative or hard paths.

Please mark this as the answer.
